userscript (violentmonkey) script runs on first page, does not run on subsequent pages
I am trying to make a userscript that will open the invoices from Amazon in new tabs, so that I can try to categorize my spending better.  It's a PITA.
Here's the link:
https://www.amazon.com/cpe/yourpayments/transactions
My script works on the first page, but when I press the "Next Page" button at the bottom and the script doesn't run on the new pages.  I've tried the different @run-at options but they don't make a difference.
I think is due to some sort of dynamic generation or loading of the subsequent pages, but I don't know how to hook that and I don't seem to be phrasing my search terms in a way that I'm getting hints on how to help it.
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Open payment invoices in new tab
// @namespace   Violentmonkey Scripts
// @match       https://www.amazon.com/cpe/yourpayments/transactions*
// @grant       none
// @version     1.0
// @author      -
// @description 2/5/2024, 12:24:35 PM
// ==/UserScript==


var TargetLink = document.querySelectorAll('.a-span12 a');

var len = TargetLink.length;

for(var i=0; i<len; i++)
{
   TargetLink[i].setAttribute('target', '_blank');
}


It's a SPA site. Instead of iterating all links add just one global click listener on window and then check event.target.matches('.a-span12 a') inside. Also use @matches for the entire site, not just this path.

Here is the code that worked.  Thanks to @wOxxOm for pointing the way.
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Open payment invoices in new tab
// @namespace   Violentmonkey Scripts
// @match       https://www.amazon.com/*
// @grant       none
// @version     1.0
// @author      -
// @description 2/5/2024, 12:24:35 PM
// ==/UserScript==


window.addEventListener("click", function(evnt){
    if (evnt.target.matches('.a-span12 a'))  {
      evnt.target.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
    }
});

